# Update two Rows of one column in one table

Tags: mysql, plsql, oracle11g

```
Lib_Issue_Id  Book No  Member ID  Issue Date  Return Date
------------  -------  ---------  ----------  -----------
7001          101      1          10-Dec-06   NULL
7002          102      2          25-Dec-06   NULL
7003          104      1          15-Jan-06   NULL
7004          101      1          04-Jul-06   NULL
7005          104      2          15-Nov-06   NULL
7006          101      3          18-Feb-06   NULL
```

I have this table with following Constraint:

1. `Lib_Issue_Id` - Primary key
2. `Book_No` - foreign key
3. `Member_id` - foreign key
4. `Issue_date <=` system date
5. `Issue_date < Return_date`

How can I modify the `Return_Date` of `7004` and `7005` to 15 days after the `Issue_date`?

Comment: Since you have added both tags: is it `mysql` or `oracle11g`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IN or OR in your update:

```
UPDATE [tablename]
SET Return_Date = Issue_Date + 15
WHERE Lib_Issue_Id IN (7004, 7005);
```